# SSRS, Visual Studio 2015, IIF statement using Or

Tags: reporting-services

Trying to figure out what is wrong with the following IIF statement:

```
=iif((Field1 <> "String1" Or "String2") 
    Or ( Field2 <> "String1" Or "String2")
    Or ( Field3 <> "String1" Or "String2")
    Or (Field 4 <> "String 3"), Field5, nothing)
```

Essentially I am wanting to filter out rows that meet iif, but when ever I try to I get the warning

> [rsRuntimeErrorInExpression] The Value expression for the textrun
>   ‘Field.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error: Input string was
>   not in a correct format.

`

Comment: You might be better off using Switch rather than iif

Comment: I have tried using either,

Comment: I have tried using both, each one gives me a #Error in the row, Tried using Ross, with both an IIF and a Switch, neither work, still the the #Error.

Comment: it seems like there is something wrong with what i am trying to do, i just tried adding a column to display 1 if the parameters above are met, else display 0, and that does not even work

Comment: @D.Minham - Are you using the correct SSRS field syntax - `Fields!Field1.Value` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
=iif((Field1 <> "String1" Or Field1 <> "String2") 
    Or ( Field2 <> "String1" Or  Field2 <> "String2")
    Or ( Field3 <> "String1" Or Field3 <> "String2")
    Or (Field 4 <> "String 3"), Field5, nothing)
```

Comment: Tried this, i am getting a #Error within the all of the Rows

Comment: Try replacing nothing with "".  It's either that or Field5 is an invalid type for the column